# C# WPF Entity Framework - Missing Runtime Assemblies for 6.0.NET

Tags: c#, visual-studio, entity-framework, entity-framework-core

Through a tutor it was suggested that to interact with an SQL Database it would be easier to use models through the entity framework.

It looks like a great much more efficient tool than what I am using now, however I cannot get it to install in my solutions.

I am using the C# WPF Application with the .Net 6.0

Online youtube and sites said to install the following:

- Entity Framework
- Microsoft Entity Framework Core
- Microsoft Entity Framework Core Design
- Microsoft Entity framework Core SQL Server

When I go into "Add New Item" --> ADO.NET Entity Data Model I get this

[image: Error Message]

I have also done the Scaffold code but that doesn't seem to work either. Not sure what I am missing

Comment: EntityFramework Core does not use the "EDMX" data model designer, it is pure code first. You can choose CodeFirst or DbFirst to make Model interact with sqlserver. For details, please refer to [Migrations Overview](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/ef/core/managing-schemas/migrations/?tabs=dotnet-core-cli) and [Reverse Engineering](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/ef/core/managing-schemas/scaffolding/?tabs=dotnet-core-cli)